# Subquery to display one column in a Table as two separate columns

Tags: mysql, finance

I have two tables

```
Ledgers Table
==============
ledger_id  ledger_name  open_bal  close_bal  dr_bal   cr_bal
---------  ---------   ---------  ---------   ------   ------  
1          Bank A/C        0       5000       5000      0              
2          Capital A/C     0      -50000      0         50000          
3          Cash A/C        0       30700      53500     22800      


Transactions Table 
==============
trans_id  trans_date  ledger_id  ledger_name   amount   trans_type 
---------  ---------  ---------  ---------    ---------  ---------  
1         2004-01-01   3          Cash A/C      50000  Dr                   
2         2004-01-01   2          Cap A/C       50000  Cr                    
3         2004-01-02   9          Purchase A/C  10000  Dr
```

These are my tables, what am trying to achieve is to get the ledgers balances for a particular month. Here am not trying to insert data into a table.

Using the above two tables i just need to query and out put the result as

```
Desired Output
==============      

ledger_id   ledger_name  amount trans_type As Debit   trans_type as Credit
---------   ---------    ------  ---------            --------- 
3           Cash A/C     50000        Dr                Null
2           Capital A/C  50000      Null                  Cr
```

So trans_type field here is displayed separately DR as Debits and Cr as Credits. This is what I want to achieve.

What i have tried till now is joining the transaction table with the ledgers! But i have failed to get the desired output just by querying these two tables.

This is what i have tried,

```
SELECT tr.trans_date, tr.amount, tr.ledger_id, l.ledger_name, tr.trans_type
FROM tbl_transaction tr LEFT JOIN tbl_ledgers l 
ON l.ledger_id = tr.ledger_id WHERE trans_date BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2004-01-31';
```

So i basically want to know how can we achieve this? trans_type column split into two "Dr" separate and "Cr" separate?

Comment: Can you change the sample output here to show rows that actually exist in your `transactions` table? The sample you posted has no rows for `ledger_id = 1` and though I think I understand the requirement, it is helpful to see _exactly_ the output that should be produced given the sample input.

Comment: The other thing I want to clarify - this looks like  you are _only_ separating `Dr, Cr` into separate columns but listing the relevant `amount` in one column. Is that correct, or is the intent to create an aggregate `SUM()` per ledger id?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, Yes you are right, i only want to separate Dr, Cr into  separate columns with their amount in one column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `CASE` to inspect the actual value of `trans_type` and display it, doing so once for each alias `Debit, Credit`. This gets unwieldy with more than a few values, but since you have just two it is a simple method.

```
SELECT 
  tr.ledger_id,
  l.ledger_name,
  tr.amount,
  CASE WHEN tr.trans_type = 'Dr' THEN tr.trans_type ELSE NULL END AS Debit,
  CASE WHEN tr.trans_type = 'Cr' THEN tr.trans_type ELSE NULL END AS Credit
FROM
  tbl_transaction tr
  LEFT JOIN tbl_ledgers l ON l.ledger_id = tr.ledger_id
WHERE
 trans_date BETWEEN '2004-01-01' AND '2004-01-31';
```

Here is a demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5623/2

Note that this uses a `LEFT JOIN`, resulting in `ledger_id = 9` being returned in the demonstration (different than your example). Changing it to an `INNER JOIN` would correct that. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5623/3)

Comment: Perfect answer, Got the desired result, _Thank you very much_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT IIf([trans_type]='dr',[trans_type],"") AS debit, IIf([trans_type]='cr',[trans_type],"") AS credit
FROM tr;
```

This code creates an IF statement, to determine whether the [trans_type] field is 'cr' or 'dr' and returns the value in trans_type ('cr' or 'dr') if the condition is met or returns a blank ("") when the condition is not met.